# webserver serve file request with delay

Tags: php, web-services, perl, delay

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to configure a webserver so that requests for files will be served with a delay. So for example if i were to serve this file http://www.example.url/picture.jpg, i want the data transfer to start only 2 seconds after the request has been made... or any other arbitrary number. The important bit is that this should work independent from how the file is accessed, so just an html solution isn't workable.

I have asked around on superuser.com and people there recommended me to look into perl or php to put something together that way that could provide me with the functionality i need. Now i do not have any experience with any of these languages mentioned but i'm assuming it wouldn't be too complicated to put something together like that, my question is... can someone help me get started?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache2 with mod_perl, then you could use one of the [`handlers`](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/handlers/http.html) to do this filtering.  However, even with the below code as an example, you're going to need to be familiar with both perl and server configuration:

```
package ImgPause;

use Apache2::RequestRec();

use Apache2::Const -compile => qw(FORBIDDEN OK);

use strict;
use warnings;

our %images = (
    '/adesert.jpg'    => 4,
    '/afish.jpg'      => 4,
    '/aflower.jpg'    => 4,
    '/ahouse.jpg'     => 4,
    '/akoala.jpg'     => 4,
    '/apenguin.jpg'   => 4,
    '/atulip.jpg'     => 5,
)

sub handler {
    my $r = shift;

    my $host = $r->header_in('Host');
    my $uri = $r->uri;

    if ($images{$uri}) {
        sleep $images{$uri};
    }

    return Apache2::Const::OK;
}

1;

__END__
```

Comment: Mmm well alright, thanks for giving me a clue in any case. I suppose though that on shared hosting it wouldn't be a possibility right? Guess i might have to go for a different package...